# KOMA script - widening text width

Tags: margins, koma-script, longtable, double-sided

I have a longtable that is about 14cm wide and the text width of 12 cm.  Therefore I would like to widen the text width on two pages  for 2 cm, toward the outer edge of the page.  I have "discovered" that there are `addmargin` and `addmargin*` environments, but I just don't have a clue how to use them.  I tried various combinations of parameters with no success.  Any idea how to do that?

Thanks

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=255mm,top=20mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=65mm,marginparsep=7mm,marginparwidth=48mm,headsep=4mm,headheight=6mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more text

\begin{addmargin*}[0cm]{-2cm}
\begin{longtable}{llll}
\hline
\hline
text & text & more and more and more text & more and and more and more text \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\hline
\endfoot

text & text & more and more and more text & more and and more and more text \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
text & text & more and more and more text & more and and more and more text \\
\end{longtable}
\end{addmargin*}

more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more text

\end{document}enter code here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got another solution, see below. I decided not to delete my answer dated October 19, 2013, because we found out that `addmargin*` won't work properly with longtable and `\LTleft` from the longtable package doesn't help much, either.

Maybe we can solve the issue the other way round: If you can put your longtable below a heading, then you could use `\newgeometry` starting from this heading with 20 mm less outer margin. To hide that, put your *text* inside an addmargin* environment, but not the table. Then restore the former geometry.

Looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{longtable, blindtext}

\usepackage[paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=255mm,top=20mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=65mm,marginparsep=7mm,marginparwidth=48mm,headsep=4mm,headheight=6mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\blinddocument


\newgeometry{paperwidth=210mm,paperheight=255mm,top=20mm,bottom=25mm,inner=25mm,outer=45mm,
  marginparsep=7mm,marginparwidth=48mm,headsep=4mm,headheight=6mm}

\section{Tabulars}
\label{sec:tabulars}


\begin{addmargin*}[0cm]{2cm}
more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more
and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and
more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more
and more and more and more and more and more and more and more text
\end{addmargin*}

\begin{longtable}{llll}
\hline
\hline
text & text & more and more and more text & more and and more and more text \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\hline
\endfoot

text & text & more and more and more text & more and and more and more text \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
% & & a& \\
% & & a& \\
% & & a& \\
% & & a& \\
% & & a& \\
% & & a& \\
% & & a& \\
% & & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
& & a& \\
text & text & more and more and more text & more and and more and more text \\
\end{longtable}


\begin{addmargin*}[0pt]{2cm}
  more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more
  and more and more and more and more and more and more and more and
  more and more and more and more and more and more and more and more
  and more and more and more and more and more and more and more text
\end{addmargin*}

\restoregeometry

\blinddocument


\end{document}
```

This is not a perfect solution because of the pagebreak comming with `\newgeometry` and `\restoregeometry`, but maybe you can deal with it when you make the final layout.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll have a look at this solution.  Fortunatelly, in my case longtable is actually part of a special subsection, which consists of the longtable and two lines of text.  I'll still keep the question open in case someone comes with more general solution.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that it influences headers and footers.  The longtable is safely within page, but header is now out of the page... :-(  Also \restoregeometry is just in front of \tableofcontents, which creates one redundant empty page between.

Comment: @Pygmalion KOMA-script allows manipulation of the width of the header using `\KOMAoptions` for the affected pages, maybe it's a bit tricky. And if the longtable is the last part of your text just before the toc, maybe you won't need `\restoregeomentry` here or at all.

Comment: Correction:  I solved the header problem simply by repeating the command \setheadwidth[0pt]{textwithmarginpar} just after \newgeometry. **The problem of empty page between `\restoregeometry` and `\tableofcontents` remains!**

Comment: Would you update your MWE? Because if I simply trade the last `\blinddocument` for a `\tableofcontents`, there is no empty page.

Comment: I solved the mystery.  Table of contents always starts on an odd page.  So this is why KOMA added a blank page.  How stupid of me not to think about that sooner.

Answer (score 0):

[[
If nothing else helps one might consider to consult the manual (you get it with »texdoc komascript« on the command line, then search for »addmargin«). However:

```
\begin{addmargin*}[0cm]{-2cm}
 \begin{longtable}...
  ...
 \end{longtable}
\end{addmargin*}
```

If it does not work, please provide a MWE. ]]

I was wrong:

---

### Edit

My apologies. You wrote, you had no clue and I misunderstood that.

Besides that, it's not sure that addmargin and longtable, see [here](http://www.golatex.de/seitenrand-bei-verwendung-von-longtable-in-latex-verschieben-t1987.html), maybe you understand German. Markus Kohm provided an example for a solution without addmargin, but I did not check it:

```
\setlength{\LTleft}{-1cm}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|}
\captionabove{Beschriftung der Tabelle}\\
Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test \\
Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test \\
Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test \\
Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test \\
Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test \\
Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test \\
Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test \\
Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test \\
Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test & Dies ist der Test \\
\end{longtable}
```

---

I found a post (http://www.komascript.de/node/1629) where Markus more or less says that a longtable inside an addmargin environment won't work.

Comment: Of course I consulted the manual and first tried what you proposed above, and failed...  I'll try to make a MWE then.

Comment: @Pygmalion See my edits: you were right and I was wrong.

Comment: The poblem with `LTleft` is that it translates to left on even and odd pages.  It should translate to left on even pages and to right on odd pages.  I speak too little German to understand this highly technical discussion.  I don't see any documentation on LTleft.

Comment: LTleft is part of longtable and documented in the package documentation (but it works as you say, which isn't quite what you want)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, I was searching KOMA manual :o/